# Css / Jquery toggle leftbar to open from right instead of left

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this css which toggles the leftbar from the left (as it's mean't to do)

```js
$('#toggleleft').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.leftbar').toggleClass('open');
  }
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.leftbar {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  margin-left: -300px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.leftbar.open {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.content {
  background: red;
  min-width: 0;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="leftbar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <a id="toggleleft" href="#">toggle left</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see its a working code but I need to the modify the css so...
My question is, how to I change the css so that it opens from the right instead?

Comment: Replace every instance of the string 'left' with the string 'right'. So `margin-left` become `margin-right`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Animating margin/padding is bad for performance. Use `transform` instead, e.g `transform: translate(-300px, 0)`.

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin-right: -300px;` in the rule for `.leftbar` and `margin-right: 0px;` in `.leftbar.open`